# How to get current action?

Tags: filters, actions

I am developing custom registration form. Is it possible to get current action (comment adding or user registration) in function? For example i am using:

```
add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'checkQuestion');
add_filter('registration_errors', 'checkQuestion', 10, 3);
```

So, from function `checkQuestion` i need somehow to know from what action it was called?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `current_filter()` WordPress function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter

Answer (score 0):

This can be un-reliable because it depends on the values coming in from the registration_errors filter, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
function checkQuestion($var1, $var2 = '', $var3 = '') {
        if(empty($var2) && empty($var3)) {
            // You are on the preprocess_comment filter because you did not receive a total of three variables
        } else {
            // You are on the registration_errors filter because $var2 and $var3 are not empty
        }
        return $var1;       
    }
```

Comment: Already found http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter